# Map route click event not working in Titanium Appcelerator

Tags: google-maps-markers, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy, titanium-modules

I'm trying to add a clickable route on Geocoder example from Appcelerator. The problem is that I'm not getting any event when clicking at the route object.

Here's my code:

```
var cord1= {
    latitude:29.078685,
    longitude:-110.971205,
};
var cord2= {
    latitude:29.081496,
    longitude:-110.959232,
};

var route1 = [cord1, cord2];
var route = MapModule.createRoute({
    points : route1,
    color : "red",
    width : 5.0
});

route.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    Ti.APP.info(e);
});

$.mapview.addRoute(route);
```

Comment: Have you tried it on another Ti SDK version or with another map module version coz code seems proper and it could be a regression-bug?

Answer (score 0):

The [Modules.Map.Route](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Modules.Map.Route) object doesn't have any events.  None of the map objects do, except the map view itself, and we can use the mapview's [click event](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Modules.Map.View-event-click) to listen for clicks, and then check the `clicksource` property to see what was clicked on the map.

The catch is that routes won't generate a click event, but [polylines](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Modules.Map.Polyline) do, so the workaround is to use a polyline and look for the clicksource in the mapview's click event.  Something like this should work:

```
var coord1 = [-110.971205, 29.078685];
var coord2 = [-110.959232, 29.081496];

var route1 = [coord1, coord2];
var route = MapModule.createPolyline({
    points: route1,
    strokeColor: "#ff0000",
    strokeWidth: 5
});
$.mapview.addPolyline(route);

$.mapview.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    //check the clicksource for 'polyline'
    console.log(e.clicksource);
});
```